# UITableViewController duplicating rows?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that is duplicating rows as I scroll down. I understand that the cells are being reused, but I just can't seem to figure out what to do to fix it. I've read through other similar posts and couldn't figure out a solution in my case.

What am I doing wrong in my code that's resulting in duplicated cells?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StringTableViewCell";

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cellIdentifier = @"StringTableViewCell";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cellIdentifier = @"StringTableViewFooter";
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Sets up the table view cell accordingly based around whether it is the
    // string row or the footer
    if (cell) {
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[StringTableViewCell class]]) {
            StringTableViewCell *stringCell = (StringTableViewCell *)cell;
            // Sets the photos to the array of photo data for the collection view
            [stringCell setCollectionData:self.images];
        } else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[StringFooterTableViewCell class]]) {
            // Sets the table view cell to be the custom footer view
            StringFooterTableViewCell *footerCell = [[StringFooterTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"StringTableViewCellFooter"];

            // Init's the footer with live data from here
            [footerCell setStringUploaderName:@"Name"];
            [footerCell setStringUploadDate:@"10 minutes ago"];
            [footerCell setStringUploaderProfileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"]];
            [footerCell setCommentButtonTitle:@"4.7k"];
            [footerCell setLikeButtonTitle:@"11.3k"];

            return footerCell;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your screenshot?

Comment: Your code only supports two rows of cells. What index paths are supposed to be for the footer and which index paths are supposed to be other type?

Comment: @rmaddy indexPath.row 0 is for the first cell and row 1 is for the footer. I have set it up in the past where I specifically place the normal cell or footer cell conditionally under their respective rows, but no change.

Comment: But you are talking about problems when scrolling the table. This implies you have more than two rows in your table. Right? Which cells are used for the other rows?

Comment: @user716216 I needed to set the footers up in this way because built in section footers 'stick' to the bottom of the view as you scroll the table. I do not want that to happen. I need them to continue scrolling with the content. Basically each section has a normal cell and a footer cell inside of it.

Comment: @rmaddy I have multiple sections in the table. Each section has the same setup. A normal cell is row 0 of the section and a footer cell is row 1.

Comment: OK, so every section has two rows then. That makes more sense.

Comment: @rmaddy correct. Do you have an idea of what's going on then?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a prepareForReuse method for UITableViewCell which is called every time it's about to be reused. You can set your StringTableViewCell's imageview's image to nil there or you can just do it on the cell for indexPath itself, as the prepareForReuse method is only encouraged to be used in resetting the state(like hightlighted, or selected) for the cell and it's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two different cells you need something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StringTableViewCell";
        StringTableViewCell *stringCell = (StringTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (!stringCell) {
            stringCell = [[StringTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        [stringCell setCollectionData:self.images];

        return stringCell;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StringTableViewFooter";
        StringFooterTableViewCell *footerCell = (StringFooterTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (!footerCell) {
            footerCell = [[StringFooterTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        // Init's the footer with live data from here
        [footerCell setStringUploaderName:@"Name"];
        [footerCell setStringUploadDate:@"10 minutes ago"];
        [footerCell setStringUploaderProfileImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"]];
        [footerCell setCommentButtonTitle:@"4.7k"];
        [footerCell setLikeButtonTitle:@"11.3k"];

        return footerCell;
    } else {
        return nil; // this shouldn't happen but makes the compiler happy
    }
}
```

Of course the code needs to be updated to show the data appropriate to the given section.

Comment: I just implemented the code here, but the same issue is still persisting. Any ideas?

Comment: If you mean that the 1st row of every section is the same and the footer of every section is the same then read the last sentence of my answer. You hardcode every section to be identical. The code needs to get data based on `indexPath.section` so each section has its own data.

Comment: I do give data to each section, but it happens to be the same array of images. The bug I'm seeing is when I perform an action on a cell. In my case I can swipe through the images in a cell and they move. If I swipe down the table as those images are moving in that cell I will come across another cell farther down that is identical. The images will also be moving. I understand the idea of putting different data in the sections, but will that fix this issue if I just put different images in each cell?

Comment: Cells get reused. So the 1st cell for section 0 may get reused as the 1st cell for section 6 (or whatever). So you need to deal with this in the call to `setCollectionData:`. It's very strange that you put the same images in every section.

Comment: Ultimately images will be loaded from different places and will be placed into their own cell. Right now they are all of the same images just as filler. How could I deal with that in the call to setCollectionData? All that is doing is essentially setting the images within the cell to be whatever self.images contains.

Comment: It's impossible to help without seeing all of the related code to adding these images to the cell and how they are updated.

Comment: I opened up a chat with some additional detail. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45969/discussion-between-jonathan-and-rmaddy